# How to check continuity of this multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Here's the function:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}{y+{1\over y}\arctan({x^2y})} & y\neq 0\\ 0 & y=0\end{cases}$$
I need to study it's continuity and I've got a hard time understanding exactly how to rigorously formulate my findings (because I don't understand everything that well), so I would like to know if my reasoning is correct.

Firstly what I found was that in $f(x,y)=(0,0)$ the function is continuous in $(0,0)$  because the limit of this function for $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ is indeed $0$.

Secondly, the function isn't continuous in $f(x,y)=(x,0)$ if $x$ isn't zero because the limit of f when $y\to 0 $ and $x$ is "fixed" is $1$.

Is this reasoning correct and complete ?

Comment: The limit of $f$ at $(x,0)$ for $y>0$ is $x^2$, not $1$.

Comment: yes indeed, my mistake

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that $f$ is continuous at $0$ although I would really like to see your calculation before confirming that your logic is correct.

Note that the limit of $f$ at $(m,0)$ for $m\ne0$ over $y>0$ is $m^2$, not $1$. This is because$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(m,0^+)}\left[y+\frac{\arctan(x^2y)}y\right]=\lim_{y\to 0^+}y+\lim_{(x,y)\to(m,0^+)}\left[\frac{\arctan(x^2y)}{x^2y}\right]\lim_{x\to m}x^2\\=0+1\cdot m^2\ne0$$which concludes that the limit does not exist since it is $0$ along $y=0$.

Comment: your last sentence really explains a lot for me, I can see how it works a bit better now, thanks a lot for that.

Comment: @notproplayer3 You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

We have that for $x=0$

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\,\left(y+{1\over y}\arctan({0\cdot y})\right)=\lim_{y\to 0}\,y=0$$

and for $x =x_0\neq 0$

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\left(y+{1\over y}\arctan({x_0^2y})\right)=\lim_{y\to 0}\left(y+\frac{\arctan({x_0^2y})}{x^2y}x_0^2\right)=x_0^2$$

therefore the function is not continuous.

Comment: ? $x^2\to0$ as $x\to0$

Comment: Why is this a proof of discontinuity? Doesn't $x^2$ go to $0$ as $(x,y)$ goes to $(0,0)$?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Now fixed, I was wrongly considering the limit at $(0,0)$. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Looks good now!

Comment: excellent, this is what I needed, I understand it better now, Thanks a lot !

Comment: @notproplayer3 You are welcome! Sorry for the confusion in the first fromulation! Bye